# Explanation for the simplification

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

While studying thermodynamic fluctuations, in the derivation for probability distribution law following result is used please explain how we arrive at this:
$\frac{\partial^{2}E}{\partial S^{2} }(\Delta S^{2})+2\frac{\partial^{2}E}{\partial S \partial V }(\Delta S \Delta V) +\frac{\partial^{2}E}{\partial V^{2} }(\Delta V^{2}) =\Delta(\frac{\partial E}{\partial S})\Delta S+ \Delta(\frac{\partial E}{\partial V})$

Comment: Can you provide some more context? What exactly does $\Delta \left(\frac{\partial E} {\partial S} \right) $ mean?

Comment: That's what I don't know. What I know is that $\Delta S$ is change in entropy, $\Delta V $ is change in volume, and E is internal energy.